# How to determine if image was clicked on

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** What i would like to do is check if the image was selected. If it was selected, to display a hidden table that will display data..

Below the the hidden table I would like to display

```
    <TABLE Border="0" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 id="display">
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" rowspan="2" style="background:white;"><input name="txtHealthPlan" value="<cfoutput>#strHealthPlan#</cfoutput>" size="30" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly> </td>
          <td rowspan="2" style="background:white;"><textarea  class="a" name="txtOPTDesc" cols="25" rows="2" id="txtOPTDesc" readonly ><cfoutput>#strOPTDesc#</cfoutput></textarea></td>

          </tr></table>
```

And here is the id I put in the a tag that contains the image:

```
<span style="margin-left:35px"><img src="images/search.jpg" id="img1" alt="Please click to open the Health Plan Search Utility" width="25" height="25" class="no-border" onclick="FindHPlan()"> &nbsp; As of&nbsp;<input type="text" name="AsPerDt" id="clicked" size="15" class="borderC" value="<cfoutput>#strAsPerDt#</cfoutput>" maxlength="10"  title="As Per"></span>
```

And I did the following javascript to determine if the image was selected.

```
document.getElementById("clicked").addEventListener("click", check)

function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("clicked").click)
        document.getElementById("display").style.display = "block"
}
```

However, when I compile and run the page, I am unable to open the link that the image is attached too.

Per everyones request, I have removed the if statement and added a onclick event. 
so I have the following:

```
      <td class="m">OPT&nbsp;<input class="borderC" id="OPT" name="txtOPT" size="20" value="<cfoutput>#strOPT#</cfoutput>"> <span style="margin-left:35px"><img src="images/search.jpg" alt="Please click to open the Health Plan Search Utility" width="25" height="25" class="no-border" onclick="FindHPlan(); check()"> &nbsp; As of&nbsp;<input type="text" name="AsPerDt" size="15" class="borderC" value="<cfoutput>#strAsPerDt#</cfoutput>" maxlength="10"  title="As Per"></span>
    </td>
```

Which displays the hidden table. However,the second portion of the data that should be displayed after the hidden table will not display.

Comment: Why do you have this check `document.getElementById("clicked").click`? If you are trying to see if the image is clicked you already know it has been or you wouldn't have entered the function.

Comment: `img` cannot contains any other tags. What you made clickable is not the image. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: get rid of the `if` statement in your check function, you're trying to do what `onClick` was built to do already :)

Comment: @Everyone Yes, I have removed the if statement but now the second portion of the data will not appear

Comment: Put your function above the eventlistener. The eventlistener doesn't know about the function in your flow when it is attaching it.

Comment: @Daniel: Okay, so it does show the hidden table. However, when I click on the image, it directs me to pop up window where the user can select the value. Once they do, the value is displayed on the page before directed to the pop up. The values associated with the selected value is not displaying

Comment: @Kevin: Yes I understand but it breaks the other function. I have done the following:  document.getElementById("clicked").addEventListener("click", check)

function check(){
        document.getElementById("display").style.display = "block"
} and it will no display no data

Comment: @ROB set a `var clicked = false`as a global variable. At the beginning of check(), add `clicked = !clicked` to set it to the opposite of itself. Then add if statements where if clicked is true, display the table. If false, hide it.

Comment: @Kevin yes I did that and it only displays the the hidden table and not the third table where shows additional info. If I remove the check and the id, the second table appears normally

Comment: @Kevin I did what you said. Set var clicked = false as a global variable, within the function check, clicked = !clicked and if (clicked == true) document.getElementById("display").style.display  = "block" else dont display. And that table shows but the second part is somehow affected by it